# Can final statements added after each iteration in a 'for .. range' loops (like in standard for loop)?

Tags: for-loop, go

In a `for task := range ch {..}` loop (iterating over a channel), I have several places where I want to step forward to the next element (`continue`); however, I need to execute an additional statement before the continue (setting a flag to mark the worker routine is currently idle), but before the next element is received from the channel - see code sample below.

Currently, I have to repeat this statement before every `continue`. This works, but is not very elegant, and a `worker.setIdle()` can easily be forgotten. It would be nice if I could set up such a "finalizer" statement at the entry of the loop, something like you could expect of a `for task := range ch; worker.setIdle() {...}` construct, but of course that is syntactically incorrect. It would be like a `defer` in a loop, which is executed at the end of each loop iteration instead at the end of the function. Is there a way to express this in Go?

```
for task := range ch {
  ...
  if (...) {
    ...
    worker.setIdle()
    continue
  }
  ...
  if (...) {
    ...
    worker.setIdle()
    continue
  }
  ...
  if (...) {
    ...
    worker.setIdle()
    continue
  }
  ...
  worker.setIdle()
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for the replies - I think the best solution (or at least another alternative) might be an anonymous function as follows:

```
for task := range ch {
  func () {
    ...
    if (...) {
      ...
      return
    }
    ...
  } ()
  worker.setIdle()
}
```

Only drawback is that the return statements might be misleading, they should probably be commented. A "defer" statement on basic block granularity (or also whole loop granularity) would be nice to have :-)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to achieve this to extract the body of the loop to a function and restructure your code like this:

```
for task := range ch {
  doSomething(task)
  worker.setIdle()
}

func doSomething(task Task) {
   if (...) {
     ...
     return
   }
   if (...) {
     ...
     return
   }
   ...
}
```

This may lead to a better seperation of concerns: One function to handle incoming tasks and the worker and on function to do the actual work.

Comment: Then you could also run `worker.setIdle()` as a deferred function within `doSomething`

Comment: You're right, I also had this idea before, and the fenction can probably even be anonymous, so it can access closure variables - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop without the range clause. Receive on the channel in the loop and break from the loop when the channel is closed.

```
for {
    worker.setIdle()
    task, ok := <-ch
    if !ok {
        break
    }
    if (...) {
       ...
       continue
    }
    ...
    if (...) {
       ...
       continue
    }
    ...
    if (...) {
       ...
       continue
    }
    ...
}
```